# Рисование графика по перевернутой таблице

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Есть [датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1seYGPoP32Xqb0wVKpzEQZWJXa__CFBqB/view?usp=sharing). Необходимо построить график по его третьему столбцу таким образом, чтобы график строился слева направо по перевернутой таблице. То есть первое значение на графике должно быть от 1 июня 2021 г. 16:36, последнее - от 12 июня 2021 г. 22:05.

Мой код

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('001500135736500B20313536.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df = df.iloc[::-1]
data = df['3.092']
plt.plot(data)
```

переворачивает таблицу в нужном порядке, но почему-то строит график так, как будто таблица не перевернута. В чем дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

matplotlib берет значения по оси x из индекса. а индекс у вас не меняется, он так же получается задом-наперед.

попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_csv('001500135736500B20313536.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=None)
df = df.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

и теперь постройте график.
как-то так:

```
plt.plot(df[2])
```